# How do I send data from express => html

Tags: html, node.js, express

So say I have some form data in **express** right, and I'm checking it against a db. Say it doesn't find the db, so I have an if then statement for that. How would I edit a p element in a **separate** html file to say 'Account not found!' upon this if statement being activated? My code would be something like this..

```js
let userData = keyv.get(username)
if (!userData) {
console.log('couldn't find user')
//edit p element with id status
}
else {
...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you are using some templating engine running with express js server. Post the code that you have till now and not just hypotheticals

Comment: Hello @bu1d3r, could you elaborate on your question a little bit more? It's hard to know exactly where your problem is. Keep in mind that Node and Express work on the server-side; if you want to display the data from the server in the client you would need to either load your data in a template file (Express works really well with ejs) or export that data in an API (Express is good here too) and consume it from a client app where you would control the way the data looks like.

Comment: So I want to check if my DB contains, then I want to change a html p element in a seperate html file to text

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a templating engine and pass the userData variable when rendering the view.

You can do something like

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    // try to get user data
    res.render('pages/index', {userData});
});
```

userData will be accessible from the view. I recommend you use [EJS](https://ejs.co/) for this, although there are other engines like [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html), [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/), etc

EDIT:
I misunderstood your question, but the answer is the same except you render different data. If the user isn't found then you can render an error message instead.

```
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    // try to get user data. do the following if the user isn't found
    res.render('pages/index', {
        error: 'User not found'
    });
});
```